# Library design - return value of prototype method is undefined unless bind is used

Tags: javascript

I am wondering why this object needs to be bound to the return object in order for this method to work.

```
function person( _name ) {

    function InnerPerson( _name ) {
        this.name = _name;
    }

    InnerPerson.prototype = {
        me: function() {
        return "Hi, my name is " + this.name;
        }
    };

    var innerPerson = new InnerPerson( _name );

    return {
        me: innerPerson.me // this only works if you add .bind( innerPerson )
    };
}

var josh= person("josh");
console.log( josh.me() ); // Hi, my name is undefined
```

What is going on step-by-step in this execution? How is `this.name` undefined when calling `josh.me()` if the object has clearly been created and the return value of the `person` object has a reference of it in `me: innerPerson.me`? Why is `bind` needed in this example?

Part of the reason for getting an explanation of this, is not just how `this` or context works in Javascript. There are specific things going on in this problem that having an understanding of `this` in a general sense does not completely explain. For example, if I called `innerPerson.me()` instead of returning the function definition, I would get the correct context. It is because of what I am returning that the context and `this` changes.

Comment: I have to ask two questions before: **(1)** Why are you replacing prototype? **(2)** Why are you not returning `innerPerson` directly? If you didn't do those things you didn't have to `bind`

Comment: This pattern keeps `name` variable private and each new object inherits the `me` function through prototype.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I said to replace. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kc26y9ge/). `_name` is still private

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question for more clarity. I want to keep `josh.name` private. I only want to return the `me` function of the `innerPerson` object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: have you considered using ecma6 class definitions or do you definitely want the answer in ecma5?

Comment: `.name` won't be private with `bind` either. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/rpk82gcs/) is how you make it exclusively private

Comment: @aec isn't ecma6 class definition just syntactic sugar for how it's all working under the hood? I would like any answer that is to my question of how this is working. Not curious for other solutions, just trying to understand how this works.

Comment: @Adelin I don't care about using a different pattern. I want to know how this current pattern is working.

Comment: There are minor details where `class` is different, e.g. it cannot be called without `new`, but mostly it is just syntactic sugar, yes.

Comment: @joshuar500 I'm struggling to understand how did you come up with this code. Afaik this is not a pattern, or it is a "mistake pattern". `InnerPerson` with its `.me` dies at the end of `person` execution, that is why it is `undefined`

Comment: @joshuar500 in that case this is simply a problem about how scoping and `this` keyword works so I'm marking it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how [this](https://javascript.info/object-methods#this-is-not-bound) works. What you want to achieve can be done as taking one `thisParent` and using it inside `InnerPerson` and its `prototype`.

```js
function person(_name) {
  var thisParent = this;

  function InnerPerson(_name) {
    thisParent.name = _name;
  }

  InnerPerson.prototype = {
    me: function() {
      return "Hi, my name is " + thisParent.name;
    }
  };

  var innerPerson = new InnerPerson(_name);

  return {
    me: innerPerson.me // this only works if you add .bind( innerPerson )
  };
}

var josh = person("josh");
console.log(josh.me());
```